# Criterion of Eisenstein

Tags: ring-theory

Prove for every $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$ that the polynomial $X^n+Y^n-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$

It is hinted that Eisenstein's criterion should be used for $Y-1\in \mathbb{C}[Y][X]$

But how does $Y-1$ divide $Y^n-1$?

Comment: $Y^{n}-1 = (Y-1)(1+  Y + Y^{2} \cdots + Y^{n-1})$

Comment: Thanks, my bad for not seing that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see it is the following factorisation:

For $n=2$: $Y^2-1=(Y-1)(Y+1)$
For $n=3$: $Y^3-1=(Y-1)(Y^2+Y+1)$
For general $n$: $Y^n-1=(Y-1)(Y^{n-1}+Y^{n-2}+\cdots+Y+1)$

Note that Eisenstein's criterion also requires that $(Y-1)^2$ does not divide $Y^n-1$, which is true because $1$ is not a root of $Y^{n-1}+Y^{n-2}+\cdots+Y+1$ (so $Y-1$ can't divide it).

Note that it comes down to showing that $1$ is a simple root of $Y^n-1$. This follows from the above factorisation, or alternatively, because $Y^n-1$ has nonzero derivative at $1$.